# Where did my minecraft worlds go?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So one day I updated my computer and then logged on to minecraft to find that my minecraft worlds disappeared.I was really upset since I wanted to play on them. I dismissed it at first but today someone told me that his phone updated and all his worlds disappeared. I have updated my computer before and never has this happened. We both play on bedrock so I am wondering if it has something to do to that. I also want to know if I recovered them. In case it is important, I didn't export all of my worlds.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably a bug i hasn't happened to everyone because it didn't happen to me when i updated try restarting the computer and also make sure your on the same account if that doesn't work then try to report this issue to mojang. I'm sorry I can't think of anything better to do just hope that mojang sees this issue bug fixes it and you get your world back.